# runtime datatype

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

what is runtime data type in c#-4.0/Vs-2010 ?
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the actual type of a variable at runtime. For example:

```
IFoo foo = new Bar();
```

The compile time type of the `foo` variable is `IFoo` and the runtime is `Bar`. The runtime type can be obtained using the [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) method:

```
Type type = someInstance.GetType();
```